# How to render a component on redirect in React?

Tags: reactjs, redirect, react-router, render, router

Here is my code

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import WelcomePage from './pages/welcome-page/welcome-page.component';
import WelcomeBackPage from './pages/welcome-back-page/welcome-back-page.component';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  let [ visitedFirstTime ] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/'> 
            {visitedFirstTime ? 
              <Redirect to = '/welcome'>
                <WelcomePage/>  
              </Redirect>
            :   
              <WelcomeBackPage/> 
            } 
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Though that is my code, I am particular curious about this part of it:

```
          <Route exact path = '/'> 
            {visitedFirstTime ? 
              <Redirect to = '/welcome'>
                <WelcomePage/>  
              </Redirect>
            :   
              <WelcomeBackPage/> 
            } 
          </Route>
```

Whenever I load the page, it redirects successfully to /welcome. However, the WelcomePage component that should be rendered does not render.

I apologize if I've made any significant React Router errors, I am new to React Router. Thank you for your time.

Comment: `Redirect` doesn't actually render any UI, it simply redirects to another url/path. You'll need to define a `Route` for path "/welcome" that renders `WelcomePage`.

Comment: Ah I see, this makes sense -- thanks a lot for your help Drew! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a route to handle the /welcome Route.
Right now you have a `<Route exact path = '/'> ...render stuff...</Route>`
This will render anything under the '/' path.
Place a `<Route exact path = '/welcome'> <WelcomePage/> </Route>` in the switch statement underneath the '/' route. The redirect will run sending them to the /welcome route.This will render the component provided by the Route (/welcome) which would be the `<WelcomePage/>`. The final code would look something like this.

```
function App() {
  let [ visitedFirstTime ] = useState(true);
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path = '/'> 
            {visitedFirstTime ? 
              <Redirect to = '/welcome'/>
            :   
              <WelcomeBackPage/> 
            } 
          </Route>
          <Route exact path = '/welcome'>
            <WelcomePage/>  
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```